# Mongodb - proper way to delete all elements in an array field?

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for the proper way to remove all elements from an array field (across all documents) in Mongodb - these appear to be equivalent, which is recommended: (or perhaps some other way?)

```
db.collection.update({}, { $pull : { 'myArray': {} }}, {multi:true} )
```

or

```
db.collection.update({}, { $set : {'myArray': [] }} , {multi:true} )
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `$set` variant will be faster as the `$pull` will have to do calculations on arrays. I am actually not even certain whether it will work, as you're not really removing any elements with your query.

Answer (score 7):

Just to make sure, do you need to keep an empty array? Because otherwise, it's probably better  to `$unset` it.

If you must keep an empty array, I believe your `$pull` call won't work - I *think* it will remove all empty elements from your array, not all elements.

Answer (score 4):

According to Mongodb's official document:

> When used with $ to match an array element, $unset replaces the
>   matching element with null rather than removing the matching element
>   from the array. This behavior keeps consistent the array size and
>   element positions.

The $set should be the proper way.